# Understanding the symbols in the Java API documentation

Tags: java, javadoc

I am new to java language and have been reading over the API documentations.  I was wondering if someone could help me with what some of the symbols mean?  For example, in PriorityQueue there is:

```
Constructor Summary
...
PriorityQueue(Collection<? extends E> c)
...

Method Summary
...
<T> T[]
...
```

My problem is around '?', 'E', 'c' and 'T'.  I think I have worked out a few, like 'T' I think is Type.  If someone could help with understanding I would be much greatful.  A link to website that describes would be great!  Thank you!

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/ and http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html

Comment: Like x in `double sin(double x)` they are free parameter names. Generic class parameter `E` probably stands for _E_lement type.

Comment: The symbols in the documentation are from the Java language. IMHO, Understanding the language is a requirement if you want to read the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that `T` is a type parameter. In this case it can be replaced by any type, since it does not have constraints.

This constructor has a type constraint:

```
PriorityQueue(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

and should be read as: create a new `PriorityQueue` instance using a `Collection` taking as type parameter any type that extends the type `E` (including `E` itself), where `E` is the type parameter of the `PriorityQueue`. Example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
PriorityQueue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<String>(list);
```

In this case `E` (the type parameter of `pq`) is `String` and the type parameter of `list` matches the predicate `? extends E`, since it is also `String`.

This would also work:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
PriorityQueue<Object> pq = new PriorityQueue<Object>(list);
```

since `String` is a subclass of `Object`, but this would fail at compilation:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(list);
```

I suggest you read more about Java generics [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Answer (score 1):

They are examples of Java Generics.

A method with a signature like this:

```
<T> public T doSomething(T t);
```

means that T can be replaced for any class. The first part tells the compiler that you want to use T as a wildcard, public T is just the return value, and T between the () is the type of argument.

This means that you can call this method like:

```
final Integer someInt = doSomething(new Integer(5));
```

But not like this:

```
final Integer someInt = doSomething(new Double(5));
```

The argument and return value must be the same..

You can also limit what T can be, for instance:

```
<T extends Number> public T doSomething(T t);
```

then the method can only be applied to subclasses of Numer, so you'll have:

```
final Integer someInt = doSomething(new Integer(5)); //allowed

final List someList = doSomething(new List()); //not allowed
```

The ? is somewhat of the same, when you have "? extends E", it means any object that is a subclass of E (or E itself).

Answer (score 0):

You should learn some basic java concepts.Stack Overflow's [java tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) has many information.

The tag's `<? extends E>` means Wildcard generic parameter that the parameter can be any generic Collection where the parametrized type extends the collection.

The "parameter" E is replaced by the programmer when using the class, e.g. `ArrayList<String>`

`<T>` is Generic class declaration.

`T[]` is Array.

`c` is variable declaration.